# Cannot connect to MS Access Database from a Java WebService

Tags: java, web-services, ms-access

I am working on Webservices.  I have written a server as well as a client for connecting to the MSAccess Database.  The server I have written has a webmethod which gives the exception:

> 'java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>   Could not find file '(unknown)'.'

But when I am executing a Java program to connect to MS Access Database, it is successfully connects. What’s is the problem? Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe your standalone program has the MS Access driver as a library, but the Webservice does not?

Comment: I think it's jdbc url problem

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the same user account as used by the web server when running the Java application? If not, then maybe it is a permissions thing, whereby your Java application user has permission to access all the files, but the web server doesn't have all the permissions it needs.

Comment: Actually, I am connecting the Msaccess database using "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=Societies_DB.mdb;"; ,its woriking fine in java application, but whenever i ma trying to connect from webservice , it cant identify the location where .mdb file stored, i have to give the file path, but i did not know how to access the MsAccess Database from another system in differen network..anyone could please help me out.